# How to sort a array of object based on range of values from each row?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a array of object which with values having ranges where I want to sort the values based on the ranges. First it should sort based on conditionalTo and then within the range on conditional from to conditionalto it should sort computationto. pls help
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vlk5m4) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0tdr1qm/)
array

```
[
    {conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 999999999999, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000}
]
```

expected result

```
[
    {conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 999999999999, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
]
```

array

```
[
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
    {conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
    {conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
    {conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
]
```

expected result

```
[
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
{conditionalFrom: 0, conditionalTo: 10000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000},
{conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 0, computationTo: 1000},
{conditionalFrom: 10001, conditionalTo: 10000000, computationFrom: 1001, computationTo: 100000}
]
```

im using lodash to sort but second level sorting is not working

```
const result = sortBy((sortBy(array, 'computationTo')), 'conditionalTo');
```

Comment: is your sample error? conditionalFrom has three `0`, but result has two?

Comment: @Terry Lennox In this case, first order by
conditionalTo - conditionalFrom
then
computationTo - computationFrom
then based on the ranges of computation from and computation to it should rearrange

Answer (score 0):

you can custom sort delegate like :

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    let ret = a.conditionalTo - b.conditionalTo;
    if (ret !== 0)
        return ret;
    return a.conditionalFrom - b.conditionalFrom;
});
```

Comment: the argument for `sort`  tells how to sort two array-item: a and b, positive is a>b, zero is a==b, negative is a<b, so you need change this delegate argument for your purpose.

Comment: it should happen dynamically... can u help me do this